# Signal loss from a JBL Eon using a XLR to 1/8" cable

Tags: audio, live

I looking to jump from a JBL Eon G2 10 to a ION Plunge Bluetooth Speaker. I have to cover around 50' and I'm hoping to use a XLR - 1/8" connect. Will there be any signal loss?

Thanks in advance!

Kenny

Comment: What do you mean by "jump from"? I'm a little confused here, Is this a mono input? Are you asking about the in/out compatibility, or the 50ft cable? I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

***Quick answer:*** if it's line level, your signal loss will be limited to the power of your bluetooth speaker.  I run microphone signal and line level signal on over 500' cable sometimes and it works fine.

**BUT**!

I can't say it's a "best practice", but it should work depending on the input.  Why the input?  Because EONS can accept a microphone as an input (there is a preamp built in) but definitely not your bluetooth speaker.
You might think that linking from the EON will overcome the issue, but sadly, the "link/thru/output" XLR connector behind these speakers are only parallel connectors.  It's basically two connectors Y'd to the same cable.  The volume of the first speaker won't impact on the next one (very handy when you are doing a setup where you need different levels in different zone but with the same signal).
So as long as you are sending Line Level signal, it shouldnt be a problem.

One more thing:  i don't know about these bluetooth speakers, but if they are real stereo speakers, you might end up with one side not wprking if you buy "THE RIGHT CABLING".  A single XLR to 1/8" is WRONG!  Even though XLR has 3 pins, it does not mean it's stereo, it means it is balanced.  So you need 1/8" to 2 XLR to get signal on both sides and since you are taking the signal from the EON, you might as well grab a Y cable so you can connect the same signal to both the left and right channels of your bluetooth thing.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using line-level inputs to the first speaker, it should work reasonably well.  If the level to the second speaker is too low, you can turn up the source and turn down the first speaker, resulting in the same volume level coming out of the first speaker and a hotter signal going to the second speaker.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be great from a gain-stage perspective, and anyway I think OP was asking about what level of signal loss to expect.